# How to remove a value from a hashmap?

Tags: java, android, arrays, dictionary, arraylist

The thing is, I have an ExpandableListView with 2 groups, inside of each group I have some users and when I click on these users I get their ids and add to a HashMap of strings, now I'm trying to remove these ids when I click on them for the second time, but the ids of the second group are not being deleted. here is what I'm trying to do:

```
aMap = new HashMap < String, GPSEscolas > ();
TextView idAluno = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.idcrianca);
TextView idEscola = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.idescola);

IdEscola = String.valueOf(idEscola.getText());
IdAluno = String.valueOf(idAluno.getText());


mGpsEscolas = aMap.get(IdEscola);
if (mGpsEscolas == null) {
    mGpsEscolas = new GPSEscolas();
    aMap.put(IdEscola, mGpsEscolas);
    mGpsEscolas.getIds_alunos().add(String.valueOf(IdAluno));
    mGpsEscolas.setAlunos(IdAluno);

} else {


    Set < String > ia = mGpsEscolas.getIds_alunos();


    if (!ia.contains(IdAluno)) {
        ia.add(String.valueOf(IdAluno));

    } else {
        alunos = aMap.get(IdEscola).getAlunos();
        ia.remove(IdAluno);

        aMap.remove(alunos);

    }

    stringArray = new String[ia.size()];
    out = "";
    if (ia.size() > 0) {

        for (String str: ia.toArray(stringArray)) {
            out += ";" + str;
        }

        aMap.get(IdEscola).setAlunos(out.substring(1));
    }
}
```

MOdel:

```
public class GPSEscolas  implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private Integer id_escola;
    private Set<String> ids_alunos = new TreeSet<String>();
    private String Alunos;
    private double distancia;
    private Float latitude;
    private Float longitude;


    public String getAlunos() {
        return Alunos;
    }

    public void setAlunos(String alunos) {
        Alunos = alunos;
    }

    public Integer getId_escola() {
        return id_escola;
    }

    public void setId_escola(Integer id_escola) {
        this.id_escola = id_escola;
    }

    public Set<String> getIds_alunos() {
        return ids_alunos;
    }

    public void setIds_alunos(Set<String> ids_alunos) {
        this.ids_alunos = ids_alunos;
    }

    public double getDistancia() {
        return distancia;
    }

    public void setDistancia(double distancia) {
        this.distancia = distancia;
    }

    public Float getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(Float latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public Float getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(Float longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to this line:

```
aMap.remove(alunos);
```

... which is the only place where you are trying to remove from a `HashMap`.

If that's the case, the problem is that you are not passing the right parameter value to `aMap.remove()`.  That method expects you to pass a `key` value, such as whatever `IdEscola` is, which is the key value you used to do a `put` in the `HashMap`.

But instead, you are passing in `alunos`, which I can't quite be sure what that is, but it looks like a list of students.

So I think that what you wanted to do was to simply do `aMap.remove(IdEscola)`.

**EDIT:** I now realize that your hashmap is keyed by school, so I changed my answer.

**EDIT 2:** And if the above is not what you want, then you probably don't want to remove anything from that HashMap.

Comment: yes you assumed all right, but how can I loop through alunos?

Comment: @WARpoluido - alunos is a GPEscolas object, which you didn't include here, so how could we be able to help?

Comment: @WARpoluido: I adjusted my answer, now that I understand your intent better.  Just do `aMap.remove(IdEscola)`.  I'm pretty sure that's what you meant to do.

Answer (score 0):

If your **key objects** are different while **putting**(aMap.put(IdEscola, mGpsEscolas)) and **getting** (aMap.get(IdEscola).getAlunos()) are two different objects then hashmap will return null even when they are logically same values.

Read about object class in java and it's equals() and hashcode() functions , hashmap class uses it.

```
Student A= new Student ("ram");
Student B= new Student ("ram");
map.put(A,"10");

map.get(B) will return null.
```

If you use object A as a key to put some element in map then you cant use object B to retrieve it , even when they are logically same .